# How to make QT Chart size larger than widget size?

Tags: qt, qchart, qchartview, qscrollbar

I am currently trying to generate a bar chart using QT. However, due to the number of entries on the x-axis, my bar chart has been squished up and the x-axis labels cannot be seen. Is there a way to make the chart larger than the widget size and enable horizontal scrolling?

[Image of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMSAD.png)

I have tried manually setting the width of the QChart object to be larger than the QChartView object but it simply squished the chart horizontally again. I also tried adding the Horizontal Scrolling policy and a QScrollBar but the scrollbar does not appear.

[Source Code #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiyuU.png)
[Source Code #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO8El.png)

Comment: Please try setting the QChartView into a `QScrollArea`. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qscrollarea.html for usage. Alternatively you can set your QChart directly into a `QGraphicsScene` instead of a QChartView. This will remove the automated layouting.

Comment: Glad to hear! Which option did you go for?

Comment: @ypnos I used the QScrollArea option. I simply added it to the UI and got rid of the original QFrame parent. Then I used the QScrollArea "set" function to add the QChartView to the scrollarea.